# System Requirements for 3d GIS & 3d Modelling

Tags: system-requirements, 3d-gis

I'm looking for system (hardwares) required for view, edit & analyse 3d GIS & modelling data.
And what is the decent monitor size should be ? single/Dual screens ?

Modern systems comes with 8GB Ram, 2GB Graphic Card, 1TB space, 3 button mouse.
But do we need anything else for a workstation ? which has decent capability for 3d GIS & 3d modelling data ?

And do you reckon 2 different set of systems for viewing and editing capable workstation ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Your question is overly vague, and is in many ways similar to an existing question (see comment by Get Spatial above). Can you look at that question, and try to rephrase your question (just click edit below your question) to tell us what you are trying to do and how it differs from the previous question?

Comment: Question seems to just be a subset of already answered duplicate identified by @GetSpatial which has been answered in detail

Comment: Which software platform  you are using for 3D GIS like ESRI or Open source OR Mix ?